# Rails 5 with DelayedJob resulting in an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, delayed-job

I have installed Rails 5.0.0.rc1 as well as the [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v4.1.2) gem. I have some code that worked perfectly fine in previous Rails apps (Rails4.2), but for some reason it keeps on failing in production on heroku now.

In short, I'm trying to send an email using DelayedJob's 'handle_asynchronously' method. I have created the mailer and added the callback in my model, but when I submit the form on Heroku, I am presented with a Rails error screen. In my logs, I am seeing an error stating 'ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)'. If I remove the 'handle_asynchronously' methods then my callbacks work. I obviously want to send mails etc. using DelayedJob however.

My code looks like this:

```
FooModel.rb

....
after_create    :send_welcome_mail
def send_welcome_mail
    FooMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
end
handle_asynchronously :send_welcome_mail
```

Like I stated, this code worked flawlessly with Rails4. Could anybody help me? Do I need to do something differently in Rails5?

Comment: Can you post the full error trace? At least a few top lines.

Comment: What attributes do you have on the model? This can also happen with name conflicts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like Delayed Job does not support Rails 5 yet:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/896

Comment: Referenced issue is closed: should be ok, now

Answer (score 4):

I think it might be a good idea to use ActiveJob as an abstraction of your queueing backend. Something like:

```
def send_welcome_mail
    FooMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_later
end
```

Then you wouldn't need the `handle_asynchronously` call.